# Grouping Elements on criteria and Finding difference between The Highest and Lowest of Group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following.

```
   Best Bid  Best Offer  Best Offer Sign  Lone Time    
0     197.0         0.0                1          1     
1     198.0         0.0                1          2       
2     199.0         0.0                1          3    
3     197.0       221.0                0          0       
4     221.0       221.0                0          0       
5     221.0         0.0                1          1   
6     222.0         0.0                1          2
```

I want to make groups of each situation where Lone time is numbers in increasing order before they hit 0(they will always be in increasing order never decreasing) and find the difference between the highest and lowest best bid values in each group. So as an example

```
  Best Bid     Best Offer     Best Offer Sign  Lone Time    diff
0     197.0         0.0                1          1          0
1     198.0         0.0                1          2          0
2     200.0         0.0                1          3          3
3     197.0       221.0                0          0          0
4     221.0       221.0                0          0          0
5     221.0         0.0                1          1          0
6     250.0         0.0                1          2          29
```

Here if you notice index 2 and 6 have values of 3 and 39 respectively. For index 2 i have taken the diff of best bid of (index 2 - index 0) and for index 6 i have taken the diff of the best bid of (index 6 - index 5). How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this here will do what you're looking for:

```
dat = pd.read_csv('dat.csv', sep=';')

dat['jump'] = (dat['Lone Time'].shift(-1) - dat['Lone Time']).fillna(-1)
dat['jump'] = map(int, (1-np.sign(dat['jump']))/2.)
dat['series'] = dat['jump'].shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum()
dat['diff'] = 0

for s, df in dat.groupby('series'): 
    dat.loc[df.index[-1], 'diff'] = (df['Best Bid'].max() - df['Best Bid'].min())

dat = dat.drop(['jump', 'series'], axis=1)
print dat
```

1) find the magnitude of the change in `Lone Time`

2) mark the last row in the series, shift it by one and fill the missing value with a zero

2.1) distinguish between series by a cumulative sum, every sequence now has its own "identifier"

3) group by series and find the span between the min/max values

4) cleanup: drop the intermediate columns